# Viscous Burgers Equation existence of solution

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Can some one prove the local existence of solution for Viscous Burgers equation using fixed point techniques.

The equation is as follows :
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} - \bigtriangleup u + \bigtriangledown(|u|^2) = 0
$$

You can assume the appropriate boundary/initial conditions

Thanks

Comment: You'll get much better answers if you state the equation in the problem.

Comment: I added the equation A Blumenthal!Thanks

Comment: I read it at first as "The Vicious Burger Equation", a horror comedy B-movie.